# How can we make horizontal UI in html?

Tags: jquery, html, css

My screen size is 1366x768 , I trying make horizontal UI for my application but did not get success . My application is a large UI which is made for drag & Drop application . I share some code of html please see . In this code there have three div elements , left-div , center-div and right div .
I want center-div have my screen size so I fix it 1366x768 but my all three div elements showing top to bottom I want show these div elements left to right with scroll because size of UI is more that screen resolution , So please anyone help me . See my below mentioned code :

```css
.left-div {
  width:500px;
  height:700px;
  background-color: orange;
  display:inline-table;
}      
.center-div {
  width: 1366px;
  height:700px;
  display:inline-table;
  background-color: #47E83D;
}
.right-div {
  float:right;
  width: 500px;
  height:700px;
  display:inline-table;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-div">Left Div........</div>
<div class="center-div">Center Div......</div>
<div class="right-div">Right div........</div>
```

Comment: According to your requirement, a scroll bar will appear in browser, which is not a good practice.

Comment: when I did position relative my element indexing issue is fixed but when I dragging element from left-div to center-div that is not showing means that is dragging but behind of center-div there have any solution for this please

Comment: There is anyone which can help me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, i think this will satisfy your requirement, if i am wrong then please let me know.

```css
.main-parent{
  width: 2383px;
  height: 700px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.left-div {
  width:500px;
  height:700px;
  background-color: orange;
  float: left;
}

.center-div {
  width: 1366px;
  height:700px;
  float: left;
  background-color: #47E83D;
}
.right-div {
  float:left;
  width: 500px;
  height:700px;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-parent">
  <div class="left-div">Left Div........</div>
  <div class="center-div">Center Div......</div>
  <div class="right-div">Right div........</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution full fill my requirement but I don't know that method is right or wrong because you fixed parent div width . I am not sure but that is good solution and hope for me . So thank you .

Comment: Without parent width it won't come side by side, If you need that to be responsive, in that case you need to handle the `.main-parent` width  through `@media`.

Comment: check out my solution. it doesn't require you to set an attribute for each of the elements. instead, you set a single attribute to the container

Comment: Hi please read everyone , Suppose I have a html input type element inside left div which is dragable . Now I drag that input element inside center div . But position of that input element left , top margin according to whole screen but Can I set it according to my center div means center div is full screen for that input element that pick pixels according to center div .

Comment: Is your dragable element is in `position: absolute`? If so, then make the `.center-div` to `position:relative`. The dragable element will take the position relative to the `.center-div`

Comment: @Samir : Thank you !

Comment: @Samir : I did but there have problem when I did position relative my element indexing issue is fixed but when I dragging element from left-div to center-div that is not showing means that is dragging but inside of center-div there have any solution for this please .

Answer (score 3):

```css
    .left-div {
         width:500px;
        height:700px;
        background-color: orange;
        display:inline-table;
    }

    .center-div {
        width: 1366px;
        height:700px;
        background-color: #47E83D;
    }
    .right-div {
         width:500px;
        height:700px;
        background-color: aquamarine;
    }
    .left-div, .center-div, .right-div{ float: left; }
    .container1{  position: relative;width: 2400px; height: auto; overflow-x:auto;  }
```

```html
<div class="container1">
                        <div class="left-div">Left Div........</div>
                        <div class="center-div">Center Div......</div>
                        <div class="right-div">Right div........</div> 
                    </div>
```

This will help you

Answer (score 2):

you need to make your body flow to the right. you can do that by adding the following to the html `body`.

this is what you need:

```
body {
  display: flex // just to make the body follow flex rules
  flex-direction: row // make the inside of the container flow as a row (left to right)
}
```

since `flex-direction` is defaulted to `row`, it should also work by specifying only `display: flex` on the body.

here's a full example:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
.left-div {
  width:500px;
  height:700px;
  background-color: orange;
  display:inline-table;
}

.center-div {
  width: 1366px;
  height:700px;
  display:inline-table;
  background-color: #47E83D;
}
.right-div {
  float:right;
  width: 500px;
  height:700px;
  display:inline-table;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-div">Left Div........</div>
<div class="center-div">Center Div......</div>
<div class="right-div">Right div........</div>
```

you can put everything you want to be ordered from **top to bottom** inside each container, and inside of them they'll have the regular flow from **top to bottom**

`flex` can be used in all modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 2):

Float is mainly for images in text. Why not use `flexbox` that is ment for layouts.

```css
.wide-ui {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  height: 700px;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100vw;
}

.left-div {
  background-color: orange;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 500px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 500px;
          flex: 0 0 500px;
}

.center-div {
  background-color: #47E83D;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 1366px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 1366px;
          flex: 0 0 1366px;
}

.right-div {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 500px;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 500px;
          flex: 0 0 500px;
}
```

```html
<section class="wide-ui">
  <div class="left-div">Left</div>
  <div class="center-div">Center</div>
  <div class="right-div">Right</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Jaager : Nice sir , I am new on html development I just know that kind of stuff but never used can you give me some elaboration how that is working are send any link about that . Thank you very much.

Comment: Satinder: Cool! I would start from here https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/.

Comment: Thank you sir please read my latest comment that is question regarding dragging UI .

Answer (score 0):

You may want inline-block for the div if you are going to be controlling sizes or margins.

```
<div class="left-div"></div>
<div class="center-div"></div>
<div class="right-div"></div>

.left-div {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  background-color: orange;
  display:inline-block;
}      
.center-div {
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-table;
  background-color: #47E83D;
}
.right-div {
  //float:right;
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

I have removed float:right; from third div style. See the demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sibeeshvenu/d42p3d0c/)

Comment: Thank you for your response but I want horizontal UI with div elements . which I did mentioned that is prototype , In real left div have many html elements like input , select  inside it etc for dragging purpose and right div have  properties which also have html content inside it . center div represent Canvas which I want full screen . When I am trying Ui effected badly .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to accomodate `2336px` of horizontal content (`500px`+ `1336px` + `500px`) next to each other  on a screen with a width of 1336px. That would normally leave 1000px of content outside of the screen. Floating content however tends to flow to the next row if it doesn't fit. Since your center elements uses all space on your screen it will automatically cause its neighbors to wrap.

Also don't expect other screens to use the same screen size. This could make the interface rather unappealing to others. I would propose to use percentages so the size of the screen is slightly less important. You could also opt to use `calc(100% - 1000px)` for the center column to always have the size of the sidebars be `500px`. This method however is slightly undersupported.

```css
[class$="-div"]
{
  display:block;
  /* Place padding on the inside; ignoring it for size definition. */
  box-sizing:border-box;
  float:left;
  width:33%;
  height:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
[class$="-div"]:last-child{width:34%;}
/* Assign some background colors. */
.left-div {background-color: orange;}
.center-div {background-color: #47E83D;}
.right-div {background-color: aquamarine;}

/* height:100% didn't quite seem to work. */
/* Force the wrapper to take all space available to it.*/
.fullsizewrapper
{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; bottom:0; left:0; right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="fullsizewrapper">
  <div class="left-div">Left Div........</div>
  <div class="center-div">Center Div......<ul>
      <!-- Large collection of elements causing scrollbars to appear. -->
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
      <li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="right-div">
    Right Div.
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone Now I am confused which one is good as per html standards . Thank you guys .